# How to create Repository for new model in Sylius?

Tags: model, doctrine, repository, entity, sylius

I'm creating a feature to add comments to products in Sylius.

So I created a new model `CommentProduct` in `src/Sylius/Component/Product/Model/CommentProduct.php`

And I defined the ORM mapping for `CommentProduct`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping
  xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:gedmo="http://gediminasm.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-extensions-mapping"                  
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                      http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd"
>  
  <mapped-superclass name="Sylius\Component\Product\Model\CommentProduct" table="sylius_product_comment">
    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
      <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
    </id>
    <field name="createdAt" type="datetime" column="created_at">
        <gedmo:timestampable on="create"/>
    </field>
    <field name="updatedAt" type="datetime" column="updated_at" nullable="true">
        <gedmo:timestampable on="update"/>
    </field>
    <field name="commentParentId" type="integer" column="comment_parent_id"/>
    <field name="commentText" type="string" column="comment_text" length="1000"/>

    <field name="userId" type="integer" column="created_by"/>

    <many-to-one field="product" target-entity="Sylius\Component\Product\Model\ProductInterface" inversed-by="comments">
        <join-column name="product_id" referenced-column-name="id" nullable="false" />
    </many-to-one>

  </mapped-superclass>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

In `Product.orm.xml`, I add the relation one-to-many for product and comment

```
<one-to-many field="comments" target-entity="Sylius\Component\Product\Model\CommentProduct" mapped-by="product" orphan-removal="true">
    <cascade>
        <cascade-all/>
    </cascade>
</one-to-many>
```

So now I want to have a repository for the model `ProductComment`, I see the other repository, that calls just like:

```
$country = $this->get('sylius.repository.country');
```

But when I call:

```
$commentRepo = $this->container->get('sylius.repository.commentproduct');
```

I have an exception:

> You have requested a non-existent service "sylius.repository.commentproduct".

**So I have to do something to have the repository for my model** ? Someone can help me ? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your resource in the SyliusResourceBundle like that http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusResourceBundle/configuration.html#basic-configuration